# Ubuntu 20.04 as a VM how to insert pipe symbol?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Hi I’m new to the Mac but have set up Ubuntu 20.04 as a VMware, using a uk apple magic 2 keyboard. I am trying to type the pipe symbol into the Ubuntu vm terminal but can’t find the correct key combination can anybody help please. Have worked the same out on a windows PC running Ubuntu as a VM but can’t get it to work on my Mac Catalina version 10.15.3  i am starting to learn about Linux using Ubuntu  terminal on a vm the subject at the minute is about piping but using the setup on my Mac i just can not find the right key combination to insert the pipe symbol which on my uk apple magic 2 keyboard is immediately to the left of the enter/return key (|) using shift and the pipe symbol works as shown here:- |||||| but how do i replicate it on a VM running Ubuntu 20.04? please can someone help? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me it was <kbd>Right ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>